# Rails - Convert unicode

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a value of this from my database:

```
what\u0092s
```

I want to convert that unicode so that it appear like

```
what's
```

Answer (score 1):

try setting within your database.yml:

```
production: #or whatever environment this is about
  adapter: mysql
  host: ...
  username: ...
  password: ...
  encoding: utf8
  collation: utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: I've tried setting that in my database.yml but still not working. The view displays the apostrophe as a square box with small numbers in it.